# Develop a workflow application in flex

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to develop a flex 3 application that would appear like a vertical/horizontal hierarchy. It will represent the flow of any application based on user selection.

Please refer to the diagram below .. I tried making a snapshot.

Can anyone help me with any tutorials for this ?

---

Here black dots represent the nodes (description) that could be furthur divided into sub-nodes having their own description.
White nodes represents the end-point of that expanded view branch. Each node represents some part of application, which if possible could be furthur expanded.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't a tree component with custom item reneder be good for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [SpringGraph component](http://mark-shepherd.com/blog/springgraph-flex-component/).  I'd start there and review that code to see if it'll work for you, or can be modified for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the help .. I also want that black node to squeeze when I click on it when it is in expanded state .. and again to be able to expand it, when its is in condensed form

Answer (score -1):

You might want to checkout [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo).  It's Flash only, but has some pretty nifty stuff.  It could be possible to look at the code and figure out a way to make it work with Flex or convert it for Flex.